# How I can hide a div when the form is valid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-hide

I hide a div in the second form and the third form if the first form is valid. The idea is that when you click on the submit button and if this is valid hide this element.

```
<div class="cover" ng-hide ="form.shipping.$valid"/>
```

I am not very clear yet how the logic works Angular these cases, if someone here can give me an idea would appreciate.

Example the my code:

```js
(function() {

  'use strict';


  var checkOut = angular
    .module('checkOutPageApp', [
      'ngResource',
      'ngAnimate',
      'ngMessages'
    ]);

  // Global controller
  checkOut.controller('globalCtrl', function($scope, $locale) {

    $scope.areaStatus = false;

    $scope.disabled = function() {
      if ($scope.shipping.$valid) {

        return true;

      } else {

        return false
      }
    }



  });

  // Controller for form Shipping address
  checkOut.controller('CheckoutShippingCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',
    function($scope, $http, $location) {
      this.data = {};
      var self = this;
      this.submit = function(valid) {
        $scope.areaStatus = false;
        if (!valid) {
          return;
        }

        self.submitting = true;

        $http.post('', self.data).then(function() {
          self.data = [];
          $location.path('/completed');
        }, function(response) {
          self.submitting = false;
        });
      };
    }
  ]);

}(window, window.angular));
```

```html
<div class="modifyAddressShipping" ng-controller="CheckoutShippingCtrl as form">
  <form id="shipping" class="shipping" name="shipping" novalidate ng-submit="form.submit(shipping.$valid)" ng-class="{'loading': form.submitting, 'is-el-dirty' : shipping.$dirty || shipping.dirty}">
    <fieldset class="billing reset-style">
      <div id="shipping_address" class="group-items-form active">
        <div class="row collapse">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- / .items-form -->
            <div class="large-12 columns items-form">
              <label>
                <input class="field field-chk" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="form.data.name" required/>
              </label>
              <div class="error" ng-if="shipping.$submitted || shipping.name.$touched" ng-messages="shipping.name.$error">
                <p class="text-msg" ng-message="required">You did not enter your name</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="chk-box">
      <div class="large-24 column box-chk-btn chk-btn-sm">
        <button ng-click="areaStatus = !areaStatus" type="submit" class="chk-btn button-cta" data-ng-disabled="shipping.$invalid">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="delivery-payment-card-chk">
  <form id="delivery_payment_form" novalidate name="formDelivery" class="min-h-3333" data-ng-submit="deliveryForm(formDelivery.$valid)">
    <fieldset class="billing reset-style">
      <div id="delivery_payment" class="group-items-form">

        <div class="large-24 column items-form">
          <label for="delivery1">
            <input name="delivery" type="radio" id="delivery1" checked>2nd Class Delivery</label>
          <label for="delivery2">
            <input name="delivery" type="radio" id="delivery2">Click & Collect</label>
          <label for="delivery3">
            <input name="delivery" type="radio" id="delivery3">48 Hour</label>
          <label for="delivery4">
            <input name="delivery" type="radio" id="delivery4">Next Working Day</label>
          <label for="delivery5">
            <input name="delivery" type="radio" id="delivery5">Saturday Courier Delivery</label>
          <!-- / label -->
        </div>
        <!-- / .items-form -->

      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="chk-box">
      <div class="large-24 column box-chk-btn chk-btn-sm">
        <button class="chk-btn button-cta" data-ng-disabled="disabled">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


<div class="sd-delivery-payment-card-chk" ng-controller="CheckoutPaymentCtrl as form">
  <form name="checkoutPayment" novalidate class="min-h-3333" ng-submit="form.submit(checkoutPayment.$valid)" ng-class="{loading:form.submitting}">
    <fieldset class="sd-billing reset-style">
      <div id="delivery_payment" class="sd-group-items-form">

        <div class="large-24 columns items-form">
          <label>
            <input class="sd-field field-chk" type="text" ng-disabled="disabled" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="form.data.name" required></input>
          </label>
          <div class="error" ng-if="checkoutPayment.$submitted || checkoutPayment.name.$touched" ng-messages="checkoutPayment.name.$error">
            <p class="text-msg" ng-message="required">You did not enter your name</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sd-items-form -->

        <div class="large-24 columns items-form">
          <label>
            <input type="text" id="card_number" name="cardnumber" card-data-type autocomplete="off" size="19" ng-minlength="15" maxlength="19" nd-disabled="" class="sd-field" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" ng-class="(form.data.cardnumber | checkcreditcard)" ng-model="form.data.cardnumber"
            required>
            <small class="checkCard" ng-class="(form.data.cardnumber | checkcreditcard)"></small>
          </label>
          <div class="error" ng-if="checkoutPayment.$submitted || checkoutPayment.cardnumber.$touched" ng-messages="checkoutPayment.cardnumber.$error">
            <p class="text-msg" ng-message="required">You did not enter your card number</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sd-items-form -->

        <div class="large-6 columns items-form">
          <label>
            <input id="expiry_date" maxlength="5" name="datacard" card-data-expiration ng-disabled="" class="sd-field txt-center p-l-0" ng-model="form.data.datacard" type="text" type placeholder="MM / YY" required></input>
          </label>
          <div class="error" ng-if="checkoutPayment.$submitted || checkoutPayment.datacard.$touched" ng-messages="checkoutPayment.datacard.$error">
            <p class="text-msg" ng-message="required">Not valid date credit card</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sd-items-form -->

        <div class="large-5 columns items-form">
          <label>
            <input name="cvv" class="sd-field txt-center p-l-0" ng-disabled="disabled" maxlength="4" ng-minlength="3" type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" placeholder="CVV" ng-model="form.data.cvv" required></input>
          </label>
          <div class="error" ng-if="checkoutPayment.$submitted || checkoutPayment.cvv.$touched" ng-messages="checkoutPayment.cvv.$error">
            <p class="text-msg" ng-message="required">Security code required</p>
          </div>
          <div class="error" ng-show="checkoutPayment.cvv.$error.pattern">
            <p class="text-msg">Security code must contain only numbers</p>
          </div>
          <div class="error" ng-show="checkoutPayment.cvv.$error.minlength">
            <p class="text-msg">Security code must be 3-4 digits</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- / .sd-items-form -->
      </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<div class="sd-chk-box">
  <div class="large-24 column box-chk-btn chk-btn-sm">
    <button type="submit" class="sd-chk-btn button-cta" ng-disabled="!checkoutPayment.$invalid">
      Place order
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following hides a form when the submit button has been pressed ONLY IF the form submitted is $valid. To work between controllers I created a variable on $rootScope to flag if the form is valid or invalid. It may be more correct to use a getter and setter function and store the variable in a service.

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="msgApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-show="form1Done" ng-hide="!form1Done">
      <h2>The Form has not disappeared</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="!form1Done" ng-hide="form1Done">
      <h2>The Form</h2>
      <form name="userForm">
        <div class="field">
          <label for="userName">Enter your userName:</label>
          <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="data.userName"
                 ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="30" required />
          <div ng-messages="userForm.userName.$error" ng-messages-multiple>
            <!-- the required message -->
            <div ng-message="required">Please enter username</div>
            <div ng-message="minlength">Username is too short</div>
            <div ng-message="maxlength">Username is too long</div>
            <div ng-message="userName">Error with username</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" ng-click="clickBtn(userForm.$valid)">Submit</button>
      </form>  
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
angular.module('msgApp', ['ngMessages', 'msgApp.controllers'])

.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.form1Done = false;
});
```

**CONTROLLERS.JS**

```
angular.module('msgApp.controllers', [] )

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.clickBtn = function(form) {
        //valid form
        if(form == true) {
            console.log("Form is valid, $rootScope.form1Done= "+$rootScope.form1Done);
            $rootScope.form1Done = true;
        }

        //invalid form
        if(form == false) {
            $rootScope.form1Done = false;
            console.log("Form is invalid, $rootScope.form1Done= "+$rootScope.form1Done);
        }
    }
});
```